# How can I format a range value amount in an outlook body

Tags: html, excel, vba

`sh.Range("P" & i + 3).Value` contains a number. In the HTML body of the email message it's formatted as plain text. How can I change this value to include commas?

Currently: `10000`

Desired Results: `10,000.00`

Comment: I was trying for quite some time (close to an hour). Just happened to be the last thing I tried while I was waiting for a response. Also, since I couldn't find a question with this answer, I thought it would be nice for anyone who runs into a similar issue to find a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Use the format function as shown below.

Format(sh.Range("P" & i + 3), "Standard")

This website shows all the formats : https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-format-function.html